# cx_Oracle callproc() method

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I'm getting an error when using callproc() to call a stored procedure with parameters.

```
cur.callproc("TEST.manage_partitions_pkg.test", ["to_date('20120525', 'YYYYMMDD')", 1,     "tablename_type('MESSAGE', 'VALID_MESSAGE')", True, True])
```

But it doesn't seem to recognize the SQL parameters. Do I somehow need to translate the SQL parameters into python? If so, how would that be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first parameter should be a [cx_Oracle.Date](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/html/module.html#cx_Oracle.Date) object which you can construct with `cx_Oracle.Date(2012, 5, 25)`.  Your third parameter I take is just a string and you're not expecting it to be a function call, which if it is, you can do with `cur.callfunc('tablename_type', ReturnType, ['MESSAGE', 'VALID_MESSAGE'])` and inline it into your procedure call.

Comment: Awesome, the first part makes total sense to me. For ReturnType, would I simply give the python equivalent return type of the function tablename_type()?

Comment: The ReturnType will be the Oracle datatype being returned by the function, so if it were to return a number it would be `cx_Oracle.NUMBER` etc.